# mysql query not getting the user data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the apigee console to test my web service using the following URIs. When I select ALL users, the query returns data ([http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4089797/Games/V1.0/index.php/users/all](http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/%7E4089797/Games/V1.0/index.php/users/all)):

```
[
{"id":"1","username":"fkhan","password":"XXXXXXXX","email":"fkhan@fkhan.com","Gender":null,"country":null,"activated":"0"},

{"id":"2","username":"bkhan","password":"XXXXXXXX","email":"bkhan@fkhan.com","Gender":null,"country":null,"activated":"0"},

{"id":"3","username":"ckhan","password":"XXXXXXXX","email":"ckhan@fkhan.com","Gender":null,"country":null,"activated":"0"}
]
```

But when I select a particular user, the query does not return any data (creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4089797/Games/V1.0/index.php/users/username/fkhan is):

```
{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}
```

I have a user called `user` in the MySQL database, and this is the PHP to retrieve the name:

```
 function users_get($users_username) {
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "'.$username.'";';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->row();
    $this->response($data, 200);
}
```

This is the query function:

```
function all_get() {
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users;';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();   
    $this->response($data, 200);
}
```

Why do I get results with ALL users, but not one particular user?

Comment: Look up variable scope and function arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have used wrong variables in your SQL command. The function is defined as

> function users_get($users_username) {

where the input variable is $users_username

but in your SQL command

> $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "'.$username.'";';

you use $username

change your SQL command as following and it should be okay

> $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "'.$users_username.'";';

Comment: ive changed it but im still getting the same problem   function users_get($users_username) {
        $this->load->database();
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "'.$users_username.'";';
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data = $query->row();
        $this->response($data, 200);
    }

Comment: thanks for accepting the response. By accepting the answer, I assume your problem is now solved. Did you sort it out? or still you have problem?

Comment: yes i have sorted this problem now onto many other problems :D

Answer (score 1):

In the method declaration you have the parameter `$users_username` but in the method implementation you use `$username`, that is your main mistake: the variable `$username` does not exist so it is `null`; replace

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "'.$username.'";';
```

with

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "'.$users_username.'";';
```

Also, consider using prepared statements instead of manually placing the variable in the query string.

Answer (score 1):

The `username` variable is not defined in the function so it's empty.
I believe you've confused with its name and meant to use `$users_username`.

```
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "'.$username.'";';
```

Replace it with:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "'.$users_username.'";';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is called `$users_username` but query is with variable `$username` so your final query is `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "";` and there is no user with empty string. :)